# Why is it not comparing my array to my input properly and adding up how many in the array are greater or = to the input

Tags: arrays, vb.net

The program is supposed to search through the array and add up how many in the array are = to or greater than the users input, but no matter what I put in it says all 5 arrays are. On the other hand, I  input 0 it gives me 0 even though all five are greater than 0.

Here is  my code please explain what's wrong and how to fix it.

```
Private Sub frmMain_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    'fills the array
    intSales(0) = 5000
    intSales(1) = 4500
    intSales(2) = 2000
    intSales(3) = 6000
    intSales(4) = 3000
End Sub

Private Sub btnSearch_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSearch.Click
    ' searches the intSales array, looking for values that are
    ' greater than or equal to the value entered by the user


    'names the veriables
    Dim intSales_amount As Integer
    Dim intEmployee As Integer

    'stores the variables 
    Integer.TryParse(txtSales.Text, intSales_amount)
    Integer.TryParse(lblCount.Text, intEmployee)

    'sets counter to 0
    intEmployee = 0

    'searches the array and counts how many of the values are 
    ' greater than or equal to the value entered by the user
    ' and stores it in the counter
    For intsub As Integer = 0 To intSales.Length - 1
        If intSales_amount >= intSales.Length Then
            intEmployee += 1
        End If
    Next intsub

    'displays amount stored in the counter
    lblCount.Text = intEmployee
End Sub
```

here is where I think the problem is

```
    For intsub As Integer = 0 To intSales.Length - 1
    If intSales_amount >= intSales.Length Then
        intEmployee += 1
    End If
Next intsub
```

Comment: `If intSales_amount >= intSales.Length Then`  you are comparing an amount to the length of the array rather than values *in* the array.  Such things are easy to find using the awesome debugger.  probably about time you read [ask] and take the [tour]. All your previous Questions are 0 or less (this one will not do much better) which will have consequences.

Comment: A) Set a break point on the `For intsub...` line b) when it stops, hold the mouse over `intSales.Length` it will be `5` because thats the ***size*** of the array not the ***value*** of anything ***in*** the array.  use `intsub` to index the array (thats why it is there): `If intSales_amount >= intSales(intSub)` .  All very easy to find and even fix using the debugger

Comment: okay  @Plutonix how do i compare the values because when I take out the .Length it puts a red line under it

Comment: He told you exactly how to fix it in his last comment.  He even gave you the code.  Did you even read it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your loop that is supposed do do the checking ..

```
For intsub As Integer = 0 To intSales.Length - 1
    If intSales_amount >= intSales.Length Then
        intEmployee += 1
    End If
Next intsub
```

is only checking if intSales_amount is greater than or equal to the number of elements in the array, not the amount that is in each element. To check it against the contents of each element in the array change it to this :-

```
If intSales_amount >= intSales(intsub) Then
```

I'm assuming that the values in the intSales array are a number relating the each salesperson's sales. If you're trying to find out how many salespersons have sales above the intSales amount, then your test is the wring way round. It should be :-

```
If  intSales(intsub) >= intSales_amount Then
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Sub btnSearch_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSearch.Click
    ' searches the intSales array, looking for values that are
    ' greater than or equal to the value entered by the user

    Dim intSales_amount As Integer
    If  Integer.TryParse(txtSales.Text, intSales_amount) Then
         lblCount.Text = intSales.Count(Function(s) s >= intSales_amount)
    Else
        'If you're not gonna do something different if TryParse() fails, 
        '  you may just as well use plain Parse()
    End If
End Sub
```